# Unity interception and multiple interfaces implemented by the intercepted class

Tags: c#, unity-container, interceptor

How can I make unity to emit decorator which implements all interfaces of decorated dependency?

Unity allows to create build aware dependencies. This is done by implementing `IBuildAware` interface and using `BuilderAwareExtension` which casts to `IBuildAware` in its internals.

The problem is that when using interception decorator does not implement any interface besides the registered one.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

public class Foo : IFoo, IDisposable
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}


container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(
    new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>(),
    new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>());
```

As the result Unity calls neither `Dispose` nor `OnBuiltUp`/`OnTearingDown` methods.

**Update:**
This interceptor also does not mirror public properties/methods with applied to them attributes. This can break custom extensions which use reflection.
`TransparentProxyInterceptor` does not have these issues, but it considerably affects performance.

**Update 2:** [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42147889/921054) about `TransparenProxyInterceptor`.

How can I make unity to emit decorator which implements all interfaces and completely mirrors public members of decorated dependency?