# How to get the value of the property of a transparent proxy via reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, interception, transparentproxy

My code receives transparent proxy instead of original instance.

While this `var type = obj.GetType();` yields the type of original class,
the following code throws `TargetException`:

> Object does not match target type

```
var value = property.GetValue(obj, null);
```

where `property` is one from the `type.GetProperties()`

Comment: What type does `type` represent here?

Comment: @DavidG obj- is an incoming object which appears to be a transparent proxy. But `GetType()` returns the type of a wrapped object.

Comment: When you say "appears to be", what do you mean?

Comment: @DavidG Real proxy of this transparent proxy is of type [InterceptingRealProxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.interceptionextension.interceptingrealproxy.aspx)

Comment: I mean that before we enabled Unity Interception it was the registered dependency, and with enabled `TransparentProxyInterceptor` it is transparent proxy. We have additional teardown strategy which uses reflection. Not it throws error when tries to get property's value. Thus TransparentProxy is not so transparent in relation to reflection.

Comment: I suspect this is some sort of restriction/bug in the implementation of `InterceptingRealProxy`. A quick test with a custom `RealProxy` shows that it is definitely possible to call `.GetType().GetProperty(...).GetValue(...)` on a transparent proxy, and have that method call (which is the property's getter) forwarded through the real proxy.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, that's fine. Will have a look at InterceptingRealProxy.